# jQuery autocomplete and handling the value / label issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to have a jQuery autocomplete. I have specified some data but when I select an item on the drop down, it always pushes the value into the meta-area elements. I want the label. How to do this? Trying to get it to show the label in #meta-area rather than the value.

**HTML:**

```
 ...
 area:<input type='text' size='20' id='meta-area' />
   <input type='hidden' id='meta_search_ids' value='' />
 ...
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data =[
        {'label':'Core','value':1},
        {'label':' Selectors','value':2},
        {'label':'Events' ,'value':3}]; 

        $("#meta-area").autocomplete({source:data,
            select: function(e, ui) {
                $("#meta_search_ids").val(ui.item.value);
                // this part is not working
                //$(this).val(ui.item.label);
                $('#meta-area').text('this is what I want');
            }
        });
    //alert("this loaded");
});
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The default action of a `select` event places `ui.item.value` inside the `input`. You need to use `preventDefault` with your event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data =[
        {'label':'Core','value':1},
        {'label':' Selectors','value':2},
        {'label':'Events' ,'value':3}]; 

    $("#meta-area").autocomplete({
        source:data,
        select: function(e, ui) {
            e.preventDefault() // <--- Prevent the value from being inserted.
            $("#meta_search_ids").val(ui.item.value);

            $(this).val(ui.item.label);
        }
    });
    //alert("this loaded");
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/UGYzW/6/

Answer (score 0):

You mean that? Change "area:" to new one?

```
<span id='area'>area</span>:<input type='text' size='20' id='meta-area' />
   <input type='hidden' id='meta_search_ids' value='' />


<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var data =[{'label':'Core','value':1},
     {'label':' Selectors','value':2},
     {'label':'Events' ,'value':3}]; 
 $("#meta-area").autocomplete({source:data,
   select: function(e, ui) {
     $("#meta_search_ids").val(ui.item.value);
    // working like this?
    $('#area').text(ui.item.label);
    // $('#area').text('this is what I want');
    }
 });
   //alert("this loaded");
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: Sorry - not getting what you're saying. Right now, it's populating meta-area with the value variable and I'd like to have the label.

Comment: It's possible to get label like this `$('#meta-area').text(ui.item.label);`. It works.